# Getting the last word from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How can we get the last word from a string using JavaScript / jQuery?

In the following scenario the last word is "Collar". The words are separated by "-".

```
Closed-Flat-Knit-Collar
Flat-Woven-Collar
Fabric-Collar
Fabric-Closed-Flat-Knit-Collar
```

Comment: I don't think it is a `localized` question. And it has been viewed by 2100 users by now. I have voted for `reopen`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why must everything be in jQuery?

```
var lastword = yourString.split("-").pop();
```

This will split your string into the individual components (for exampe, `Closed`, `Flat`, `Knit`, `Collar`). Then it will pop off the last element of the array and return it. In all of the examples you gave, this is `Collar`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Your correct, I should have just said JS.

Answer (score 8):

```
var word = str.split("-").pop();
```

Answer (score 6):

I see there's already several `.split().pop()` answers and a `substring()` answer, so for completness, here's a Regular Expression approach :

```
var lastWord = str.match(/\w+$/)[0];
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XyAF5/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery to do this. You can do with pure JavaScript:

```
var last = strLast.split("-").pop();
```

Answer (score 3):

`Pop` works well -- here's an alternative:

```
var last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, str.length);
```

- [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QvtfH/)

Or perhaps more simplified as per comments:

```
var last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
```

Comment: The second argument of `substring` is optional. Omitting it will return everything up to the end of the string.

Comment: @Kolink -- agreed, just have always been explicit.  I prefer using `pop`, just like to alter alternative option.  Thanks.