# How to get the last word of a sentence using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the last word of a sentence using jQuery?

**Examples:**

- `get the last word of a sentence` should return `sentence`
- `get the last word` should return `word`

Comment: what do you mean by saying in jQuery?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7a7qntwL/

Comment: How can I dry my clothes in jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
var lastword = str.split(" ").pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using JavaScript. Why JQuery?

This will `split` your string into the individual components then it will pop off the last element of the array and return it.

[More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119959/getting-the-last-word-from-a-string-in-javascript)

```js
alert("get the last word of a sentence".split(" ").pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var arr = str.split(' ');

var length = arr.length;

var result = arr[length - 1];

return result;
```

Or you can try this also.

```
var lastitem = str.split(" ").pop();
```