# Wrap the last word of a paragraph in span tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello say I have the following html:

`<p>Phasellus sit amet auctor velit, ac egestas augue.</p>`

I would like to wrap the last word in span tags so the result will be:

`<p>Phasellus sit amet auctor velit, ac egestas <span>augue.</span></p>`

The logic would be something like:

```
var paragraph = $("p");
var lastWord = /* target the last word */
lastWord.wrap("<span></span>");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last word from a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119959/getting-the-last-word-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I saw that post already, they are splitting the words at the dash, I dont have dashes in my paragraph

Comment: Split by space instead then?

Comment: I found the answer here https://gist.github.com/ramseyp/5005344

Comment: Good - make an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope this code is helpful for you :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
  
 $('p').html(function(){ 
  // separate the text by spaces
  var text= $(this).text().split(' ');
  // drop the last word and store it in a variable
  var last = text.pop();
  // join the text back and if it has more than 1 word add the span tag
  // to the last word
  return text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? ' <span class="last">'+last+'</span>' : last);   
 });

});
```

```css
span{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Phasellus sit amet auctor velit, ac egestas augue.</p>
```

Comment: yes this is the exact code i posted in the comments haha thanks though

Comment: Your Welcome sir :)

Answer (score 1):

I broke this problem down into multiple steps for an easier understanding of what must be done - Hope it helps:

```
const paragraph = $('p');

let paragraphWords = $(paragraph).text().split(' ');

let lastWordIndex = paragraphWords.length - 1;
let lastWord = paragraphWords[lastWordIndex];
let lastWordModified = `<span>${lastWord}</span>`;

paragraphWords[lastWordIndex] = lastWordModified;

let newParagraphWords = paragraphWords.join(' ');

$(paragraph).html(newParagraphWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// target the string
const string = document.querySelector('.string');

// split the words of the string into an array
const wordsOfStringArray = string.innerHTML.split(' ');

// isolate the last word and remove from string
const lastWordOfString = wordsOfStringArray.pop();

// wrap the last word in a span tag to style independently
const newStringHTML = `
    ${wordsOfStringArray.join(' ')} <span class="last">${lastWordOfString}</span>
`;

// finally, replace the HTML with the new markup
string.innerHTML = newStringHTML;
```

```css
.last {
    /* knock urself out */
    color: tomato;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p class="string">Phasellus sit amet auctor velit, ac egestas augue.</p>
```