# Remove word before the slash with jquery

Tags: javascript

How to remove word before slash using jquery?

```
/bis/admin
```

In my case, I want to remove "bis". any help?

Comment: basic regular expression with replace.

Comment: I already try some code but second remove is remove

Comment: So you want result as /admin ?

Comment: You can go with regular expressions and `String::replace()`. Another alternative could be: `input.split(/(?=\/)/g).slice(1).toString()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the last word from a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119959/getting-the-last-word-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript `split` method

```js
var text = "/bis/admin";
var result = text.split("/"); 

console.log(result[result.length - 1]);
```

Another example

```js
    var text = "/bis/admin/dashboard";
    var result = text.split("/"); 

    console.log(result[result.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following using a regular expression

```
 var el = '/bis/admin';
 var newEl = el.replace(/^.*\//, "");
```

newEl will be 'admin'

Comment: Thank you sir, very big help for me. I can now proceed to my other task

Comment: Don't forget to tick the arrow next to the answer that resolved the issue for you @JohnCrisMañabo

Comment: `/^.*\//` would work the same. The character class and the capturing group are not necessary.

Comment: @Paulpro cheers - have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

split string with `/`.

```js
var strn = "/bis/admin";
console.log(strn.split("/")[2]);
```

Or you can simply use regex

```js
var strn = "/bis/admin";
console.log(strn.replace(/^\/([^/]*)\//,""));
```

Comment: but why it has two forward slash ?

Comment: @JohnCrisMañabo check my response

Comment: @JohnCrisMañabo I have updated my answer

Comment: noted sir @jremi

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
let myString = '/bis/admin';
myString.split('/')[myString.split('/').length-1];
```

Comment: Great answer . It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "/bis/admin";     
var splitStr = str.split("/");
var out = "/" + n[n.length - 1] //Out contains /admin
```